# Подмена содержимого сайта. Куда копать?

Tags: wordpress, безопасность

Сегодня случайно и с удивлением обнаружил, что в нескольких (не то чтобы старых, но и не новых) записях подменено содержимое с ссылками на иностранные киносайты. Сайт многопользовательский, но все, что пишет/редактирует пользователь перед публикацией идет на проверку ко мне. А ко мне эта гадость на проверку точно не приходила. Очевидно, что сайт взломали. Но куда копать - не понятно. Потому что:

1. Доступ к админке хостинга - только после смс-подтверждения.
2. FTP доступ - только с моего IP.
3. Файлы движка все одной даты, когда переходил на новую версию. Версия WP 4.7.0.
4. Тема - рукописная.
5. Плагинов всего пара, но они просты и точно безопасны (типа rus-to-lat).

Т.е. как таковых дыр нет.

а) Смущают несколько строк в .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Но дата обновления файла старая, возможно это все же добавлял не злоумышленник, а я, когда переходил на https
Честно говоря, я не очень в этом понимаю.

б) Есть еще вариант, что это просто подобрали мой пароль админа сайта. Поэтому подмена содержимого постов ко мне на проверку и не приходила. Но это даже звучит маловероятно - это ж сколько нужно перебирать-то паролей. Поэтому как-то не очень верится.

Где еще могут быть слабые места? Как можно подменить содержимое "мимо проверки" админом?
Господа, буду благодарен за любые подсказки куда копать и что искать.
Спасибо.

PS. Похоже, таких взломанных сайтов [очень много](https://www.google.com/search?q=vuln%20path%20it%20now&lr=lang_ru).

Answer (score 0):

Способов проникновения и взлома достаточно много. Это могут быть и дыры в плагинах или темах (привет рукописной теме), перебор паролей (боты ведут его круглосуточно), взлом соседнего сайта на хостинге и распространение вируса к вам (если хостер не соблюдает некоторые меры безопасности) и т.д. и т.п. В любом случае взлом - это НЕ уязвимость WordPress, который не содержит в себе известных уязвимостей, а какая-то дыра в плагине, теме, хостинге и проч. Кстати, поскольку WordPress регулярно выпускает обновления безопасности, то держать старую версию ядра (4.7.0) - неблагоразумно.

Даты файлов не говорят ни о чём - проверять надо содержимое по контрольным суммам. Проще всего для этого использовать какой-нибудь сканер вроде [WordFence](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) (более 2 миллионов установок, так что этому бесплатному плагину можно доверять). Просканируйте им сайт, и оставьте включённым. Он дополнительно отсекает ботов при попытке перебора паролей, и следит за состоянием сайта, проводя регулярный мониторинг.

Comment: Это точно не плагин и точно не тема - я оставил ссылку на список других взломанных сайтов. И среди них тотальный разнобой. Общих тем и плагинов просто нет.

Comment: Возможно, что и не плагин и не тема. Вы поставили сканер? Какие результаты сканирования?

Comment: Да, поставил. Все чисто.

Comment: Либо база заражена js-скриптами, либо вирус был раньше перекрыт каким-то обновлением. Ну, либо у хостера дыра. Вам лучше нанять специалиста, который найдёт источник заражения и почистит базу от последствий (лишних ссылок)